# CKFinder Not Actually Uploading Images

Tags: codeigniter, ckeditor, codeigniter-2, image-uploading, ckfinder

I am using CKEditor + CKFinder to create a blog post with images in a custom CMS. The issue is that CKFinder isn't actually uploading the images to the directory I have stated in my config file. The path is correct but the uploading doesn't actually take place.

Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow [this guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/PHP/Configuration/Quick_Start)? You have to set the $baseUrl and $baseDir, and set CheckAuthentication.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems your having difficulty trying to install/config some of the file managers you mention in this post and others.

Might I suggest a really easy file manager to install:

[an-open-file-manager-for-ckeditor-3-0](http://labs.corefive.com/2009/10/30/an-open-file-manager-for-ckeditor-3-0/)

It even lets you take care of your own security/authentication

**Initializing is as easy as:**

```
CKEDITOR.replace('wysiwyg', {
               filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'ckeditor/Filemanager/index.html'
            });
```